# Embed YouTube live chat not detecting session and always prompt users to sign in

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I need to embed YouTube's live chat into my website through an iframe. I found similar questions in this forum but nothing seems to help me solve my problem.

For some reason, it always asks to "Sign in to chat" despite me already signing in to my YouTube's account. It especially happens in non-chrome
browsers.

[image]

These are the codes that I'm currently using:

```
<iframe
          src={`https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=${videoId}&embed_domain=${domain}`}
          title={`${title}-chat`}
        />
```

May I know if I have missed anything? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *It especially happens in non-chrome website.* - you mean *browser*? - if so, please verify in which browser(s) this code is working, then [edit] your question with your results. Check also you're logged on said web browsers.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Yes, I meant browser. It happens in Firefox and Safari, also Chrome incognito as far as I tried. I am logged in to all the browsers too. So clicking in on the sign in button will bring me to YT page where I am already logged in, but when I'm back to my site it's still showing the sign in button. This does not happen in Chrome where it automatically detects that I am logged in and allows me to write comments directly.

Comment: That's strange, tbh. Have your search on the internet and here on Stack Overflow if someone else has this same (*or similar*) issue? - I can't tell if you can post this issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc), but, it might be worth try it, though, I would keep searching - maybe it's a bug with the website itself - [see here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274654846). Sorry for be not more useful.

Comment: Thanks! @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes 

Quick update: created an issue on Issue Tracker like you suggested and it turns out that the feature is not available yet (thread: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/277822267). Will keep this question open in case there are viable solution in the future

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and for me it was the ad/tracking blocker on my browser that caused the sign-in button to always pop up rather than permitting me to submit messages via the embed.

Once I disabled ad/tracking blocking on **my site** (I didn't disable it for youtube.com), I was no longer prompted to sign-in.

I presume the ad/tracking blocking was doing its job preventing some information being sent to the site within the iframe.  This might be depriving YouTube of getting session data or YouTube not acknowledging the session data because of some critical data being blocked.

This makes sense since you were being prompted when in Chrome Incognito and not a normal Chrome window.  Although for Safari and FireFox, perhaps it's more because it's just not supported, as you've discovered via Google's issue tracker.